# How to insert data from List into ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have created a List called `employees` and I want to input all of the information from that `List` into a list box on the form.

I cannot believe I have forgotten this I have had a look around and I cannot find any concise information, I have a study book, but they use a `TextBox` instead of a `ListBox` and they only work with arrays and simple data types.

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
```

This is the list, it contains `employees`

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee(1111, "Name", "Skill Set");
```

I have created an instance of `List`

Then I add it to the list box on the form

```
lstFree.Items.Add(employees);
```

Yet it only appears as 'collection'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
Employee employee1 = new Employee(1111, "Name", "Skill Set");
Employee employee2 = new Employee(2222, "Name", "Skill Set");
employees.Add(employee1);
employees.Add(employee2);

foreach(var empl in employees)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(empl.ToString());
}
```

In Employee class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return ""; // return what you need
}
```

Comment: So is there a way to put the `employees.Add(xxxx)` into a loop so it automatically adds them depending on how many instances there are inside of the `list`

Comment: Yes just replace `listBox1.Items.Add(empl.ToString());` with `listBox1.Items.Add(new Employee(2222, "Name", "Skill Set").ToString());`.

Answer (score 4):

The `Add` method expects a single instance of your class. When you pass a collection to it, it calls `ToString()` and you end up seeing the full class name of the collection. Not what you want.

Instead, you could use a loop:

```
foreach (var emp in employees)
    lstFree.Items.Add(emp);
```

Or just assign it to `DataSource`:

```
listBox1.DataSource = employees;
```

You'll also want to tell it which property to display to the user (and optionally, which property to use as the underlying value):

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "EmpId";   // guessing what your class properties might be called
```

Comment: Whilst your comment was helpful and probably the best suited, I couldn't manage to get the DataSource working on my GUI form, it crashed or something, so unfortunately I had to hand the best answer to another person, I upvoted you though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using AddRange.

```
object[] arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(i=>(object)i).ToArray();
```

Compare time of this

```
// 1,29s
foreach (int i in arr)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(i);
}
```

to this

```
// 0,12s
listBox1.Items.AddRange(arr);
```

Comment: I am always looking for more efficient code, I thank you for helping me develop my own skills.